# dimension-independent classes using variardic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I've got a scientific library that simulates two and three dimensional engineering problems. The 2D and 3D codes are very similar but handwritten specifically for 2D and 3D problems. For instance a simple `point` class explicitly has separate implementations in 2D and 3D.

I'm very new to `c++11` but based on things I've read about it I have decided to test new features to seamlessly combine these codes into a dimension-independent framework. My first try was writing a simple generic `point` class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

template<unsigned short dim, typename T=double>
class point{
    const T x[dim]; 

public:
    template<typename... X>
    point(X... xs): x{xs...} 
    {
        static_assert(dim>0, "A point needs to at least have one component");
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const point<dim,T>& p)
    {
        os << "(";
        for (unsigned short i=0; i<dim-1; i++)
            os << p.x[i] << ", ";
        os << p.x[dim-1] << ")" << std::endl;

        return os;
    }
};

int main(){
    point<3> p = {3., 4.};
    std::cout << p;
    return 0;
}
```

which works fine except I have two issues/questions. First and foremost, why do I need to template parameters `T` and `X`? Why cant I tell the compiler to use the same template parameter for the variardic constructor? To me, this seems like a reasonable request!

Second, if I ever try `point<2> p = {3, 5};` I get yelled at that `narrowing conversion of ‘xs#0’ from ‘int’ to ‘const double’ inside { } [-fpermissive]`. Why cant I initialize a double from an integer? I never thought that was illegal. Is this new to `c++11` and if so what's the workaround here?

Comment: The `static_assert` is done at compile time, so you don't need to have it in a function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Interetsing. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) and use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of an array:

```
template<unsigned short dim, typename T=double>
class point{
    static_assert(dim>0, "A point needs to at least have one component");
    const std::vector<T> x;

public:
    point(std::initializer_list<T> xs): x{xs} 
    {}

    ...
};
```

Comment: but I like static dimensional check of the compiler. Would `std::array` be a better choice instead of `std::vector` here or there is no hope for static check when using `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: @GradGuy Unfortunately [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) don't have a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list` (or any specialized constructor at all), so you're back att using a variadic template constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the problem by forcing the compiler to cast inputs back to `T`:

```
template<unsigned short dim, typename T=double>
class point{
    static_assert(dim>0, "A point needs to at least have one component");
    const T x[dim]; 

public:
    template<typename... X>
    point(X... xs): x{static_cast<T>(xs)...} {}        
};
```

Although this is just awkward and I do not understand the rationale behind this change in the standard, this might be useful to someone!

Comment: You can *convert* an `int` to a `double`, but you must not initialize an `double` with a `int` inside a braced-init-list, like `int i{42}; double d{i};`. The rationale is to prohibit lossy conversions. For example, not every value of a 64-bit `int` might be exactly representable in a 64-bit `double`. I'd recommend you write an `implicit_cast` function template, e.g. `template<class To,class From>To implicit_cast(From&& f){return std::forward<From>(f);}` instead of using the `static_cast` as it's closer to having a `point::point` taking N parameters of type `To`.